# String handling in C#

Tags: c#, parsing

I develop console appication C# for a text file with some characters in it with many lines.

°¢³Ç [A1 cheng2] /(N) Acheng (city in Heilongjiang)/

°¢¶àÄáË¹ [A1 duo1 ni2 si1] /Adonis/

°¢¶û°ÍÄáÑÇ [A1 er3 ba1 ni2 ya4] /Albania/

°¢¶û°ÍÄáÑÇÈË [A1 er3 ba1 ni2 ya4 ren2] /Albanian (person)/

°¢¶û·¨ [a1 er3 fa4] /alpha/

°¢¶û¼°¶û [A1 er3 ji2 er3] /Al

I want the characters between [] and written to another text file with new line. I dont know how to implement in C#.
what i have tried till now doesnt work.
'''

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string textFile = "input.txt";
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(textFile);

        foreach (string line in lines)
        { 



        String[] spearator = { "[ ","]", "/" };
        Int32 count = 3;

        String[] strlist =line.Split(spearator, count,
               StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        foreach (String s in strlist)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use some of the C# string methods & File Stream Class.

- SubString to separate the string which has [].
- IndexOf is to get the index of the [ or ] character.
- FileStream to write the data to file.

Check out the below C# Code.

```
string[] stringArray = { "°¢³Ç [A1 cheng2] /(N) Acheng (city in Heilongjiang)",
                        " °¢¶àÄáË¹ [A1 duo1 ni2 si1] /Adonis/",
                        "°¢¶û°ÍÄáÑÇ[A1 er3 ba1 ni2 ya4] /Albania/",
                        "°¢¶û°ÍÄáÑÇÈË[A1 er3 ba1 ni2 ya4 ren2] /Albanian(person)/",
                        "°¢¶û·¨ [a1 er3 fa4] /alpha/",
                        "°¢¶û¼°¶û[A1 er3 ji2 er3] /Al"
                            };

        using (var fileStream = new FileStream("stringToFile.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            foreach (var dataItem in stringArray)
            {
                var firstIndex = dataItem.IndexOf("[");
                var stringFirst = dataItem.Substring(firstIndex + 1);
                var lastIndex = stringFirst.IndexOf("]");
                var stringToFile = stringFirst.Substring(0, lastIndex);
                byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToFile);

                fileStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
            fileStream.Close();
        }
```

Comment: yeah thanks its working ,just added \n to stringToFile .output is correct

Comment: Indeed that was needed. :)